# Recuperar posição ou nome de um botão com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como fazer para recuperar a posição de um botão na página **HTML** utilizando **Javascript**?

A ideia principal é adicionar um *eventListener* em todos os botões que foram criados no **HTML**, e quando eu clicar no botão escolhido, ele execute a função nele colocada. Até aqui está funcionando normalmente. O problema  é que na função ele não consegue recuperar a posição do botão clicado e, consequentemente, ele não recupera corretamente o nome do botão para realizar a comparação desejada para então executar o código desejado.

No código que tentei fazer, ele sempre retorna a primeira posição da coleção de elementos de botões. Logo, ele entra apenas no primeiro *if*. O desejado é ele entrar dentro do *if* que corresponde ao nome do botão.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", message);
    }
    
    function message(){
        
        for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
            
            if(buttons[i].name == "green"){
                alert("GREEN");
                break;
            }else if(buttons[i].name == "blue"){
                alert("BLUE");
                break;
            }else if(buttons[i].name == "yellow"){
                alert("YELLOW");
                break;
            }
        }
        
            
    }
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.clearfix:after{
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

h1{
    font-family: 'ostrich-sans', sans-serif;
    
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.container{
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 300px;
}



button{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: 'ostrich-sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: background 1s;
    outline: none;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
        <h1>---</h1>
        <div class="box-color">
            <div class="choose-color">
                <button name="green"> Green </button>
                <button name="blue"> Blue </button>
                <button name="yellow"> Yellow </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A minha resposta foi util?

Comment: Claro que foi! Grato por ter me ajudado rapidamente!
Só não entendi muito bem o motivo de você ter usado o this como solução. É para referenciar o posicionamento do elemento?

Comment: Quando tens um oscultador de evento assim `buttons[i].addEventListener("click", message);` ele vai chamar a função `message` passando o elemento clicado como `this`. E o `name`  é uma propriedade do elemento daí `this.name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que queres usar `this.name` dentro desse callback e não percorrer os `button` de novo pois aí dá sempre `GREEN`. Ou seja da maneira que estás a fazer em nenhuma parte do código é usado o elemento que foi clicado.

Sugestão de código:

```
function message() {
    var name = this.name;
    if (name == "green") {
        alert("GREEN");
    } else if (name == "blue") {
        alert("BLUE");
    } else if (name == "yellow") {
        alert("YELLOW");
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prfrgnf6/

Comment: Se o atributo `name` for sempre o texto a apresentar pode fazer simplesmente `function message() {
alert(this.name);
}` não é preciso tanto `if`